# including files in a symlink directory when backing up with duplicity

Tags: backup, duplicity

I'm backing up using Duplicity, great tool.
I'm unable to include files in the backup that are within a directory that is a symlink.

Using the following:

```
duplicity <dup args> --include /var/www/**/current --exclude '**'
```

duplicity will only backup the symlink
I've tried:

```
duplicity <dup args> --include /var/www/**/current/* --exclude '**'
# and
duplicity <dup args> --include /var/www/**/current/** --exclude '**'
```

Not even then symlink is backed up.

the "current" directory links to directory like:
/var/www/host.com/de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a0bd17d9b100db4b3

The files contains a few static html & css files.
I want those files to be backed up, regardless of which sha'd directory "current" points to.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Duplicity [doesn't follow symlinks by design](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.backup.duplicity.general/2766). This is because if you tried to restore from that, it'd restore the actual files, and not a symlink! It's not a very good backup if it doesn't restore things to the way they were before. It should, however, be able to backup the symlink itself, and then you should make a backup of the symlink'd data separately.

Comment: Yeh my script just need to be a little smarter about the way it decides what's going to be included. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Duplicity 0.8, the `--copy-links` flag should do exactly what you want: [https://code.launchpad.net/~horgh/duplicity/copy-symlink-targets-721599](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ehorgh/duplicity/copy-symlink-targets-721599)

> This allows us to dereference and include what symlinks point to in our backup.
>
> I named the argument `--copy-links`. This is the name rsync gives to a similar flag.